# Using _mm_aeskeygenassist_si128 to match reference values

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, aes, aes-ni

I am trying to get EAX working using Intel SI. Using the paper at https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.197.pdf, I have an input key of:

```
Cipher Key = 2b 7e 15 16 28 ae d2 a6 ab f7 15 88 09 cf 4f 3c
```

And am trying to match the second expanded key which looks like it should be:

```
rk[1] = A0 FA FE 17 88 54 2C B1 23 A3 39 39 2A 6C 76 05
```

I've grabbed various snippets using Intel intrinsics from online, for example: https://www.thesalmons.org/john/random123/releases/1.09/docs/aes_8h_source.html. They all converge on a different value:

```
rk[1] = C0 7F 9F 93 E8 D1 4D 35 43 26 58 BD 4A E9 17 81
```

Here's a sample snippet that I'm using:

```
#include <wmmintrin.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>

void dump(const char *banner, __m128i v) {
    printf("%s: ", banner);
    uint16_t *v64val = (uint16_t*) &v;
    for (int i =0; i < 4; ++i) {
        printf("%02X\n", *(v64val+i*2+1));
        printf("%02X\n", *(v64val+i*2));
    }
}

__m128i AES_128_ASSIST (__m128i temp1, __m128i temp2) { 
    __m128i temp3; 
    temp2 = _mm_shuffle_epi32 (temp2 ,0xff); 
    temp3 = _mm_slli_si128 (temp1, 0x4);
    temp1 = _mm_xor_si128 (temp1, temp3);
    temp3 = _mm_slli_si128 (temp3, 0x4);
    temp1 = _mm_xor_si128 (temp1, temp3);
    temp3 = _mm_slli_si128 (temp3, 0x4);
    temp1 = _mm_xor_si128 (temp1, temp3);
    temp1 = _mm_xor_si128 (temp1, temp2); 
    return temp1; 
}

void AES_key_expansion_raw(uint32_t key[], __m128i *ret) {
    __m128i rkey, tmp2;
    ret[0] = rkey = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)key);

    tmp2 = _mm_aeskeygenassist_si128(rkey, 0x1);
    rkey = AES_128_ASSIST(rkey, tmp2);
    ret[1] = rkey;

    tmp2 = _mm_aeskeygenassist_si128(rkey, 0x2);
    rkey = AES_128_ASSIST(rkey, tmp2);
    ret[2] = rkey;

    tmp2 = _mm_aeskeygenassist_si128(rkey, 0x4);
    rkey = AES_128_ASSIST(rkey, tmp2);
    ret[3] = rkey;

    tmp2 = _mm_aeskeygenassist_si128(rkey, 0x8);
    rkey = AES_128_ASSIST(rkey, tmp2);
    ret[4] = rkey;

    tmp2 = _mm_aeskeygenassist_si128(rkey, 0x10);
    rkey = AES_128_ASSIST(rkey, tmp2);
    ret[5] = rkey;

    tmp2 = _mm_aeskeygenassist_si128(rkey, 0x20);
    rkey = AES_128_ASSIST(rkey, tmp2);
    ret[6] = rkey;

    tmp2 = _mm_aeskeygenassist_si128(rkey, 0x40);
    rkey = AES_128_ASSIST(rkey, tmp2);
    ret[7] = rkey;

    tmp2 = _mm_aeskeygenassist_si128(rkey, 0x80);
    rkey = AES_128_ASSIST(rkey, tmp2);
    ret[8] = rkey;

    tmp2 = _mm_aeskeygenassist_si128(rkey, 0x1b);
    rkey = AES_128_ASSIST(rkey, tmp2);
    ret[9] = rkey;

    tmp2 = _mm_aeskeygenassist_si128(rkey, 0x36);
    rkey = AES_128_ASSIST(rkey, tmp2);
    ret[10] = rkey;
}

int main() {
    printf("INTEL:\n");
    __m128i rdkeys[11];
    uint32_t key[] = {0x2b7e1516, 0x28aed2a6, 0xabf71588, 0x09cf4f3c};
    AES_key_expansion_raw(key, rdkeys);
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
        dump("RK", rdkeys[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I don't quite get from reading the docs for _mm_aeskeygenassist_si128 how I'm supposed to use it to generate round keys, and I'm even more confused with the various implementations that I see which seem to generate round keys that don't match the AES specification.

Any ideas on how to reconcile? Thanks!

Comment: Here is the document you want from Intel: [Intel Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) New Instructions Set](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/white-paper/advanced-encryption-standard-new-instructions-set-paper.pdf). It explains how to use the AES instruction set. It is too bad ARM and POWER8 did not provide the same quality guidance. The usage of `_mm_aeskeygenassist_si128` should look similar to [`aes_ni.cpp`](https://github.com/randombit/botan/blob/master/src/lib/block/aes/aes_ni/aes_ni.cpp) from Botan.

Comment: What happens if you reverse the bytes in the word, e.g. instead of `0x2b7e1516` use `0x16157e2b`? Note that Intel processors are *little endian*! Beware that the output words may also be in the "wrong" order (put "wrong" within quotation marks for little endian aficionados).